# SoapServerException when calling GetListItems

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to call GetListItems in a specific calendar in sharepoint site. However everytime I try to call GetListItems I get an error saying:

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException'
```

My calendar is in a sharepoint site whose URL is:

```
https://myteam.company.com/sites/TeamSite/Lists/Calendar
```

My url for my lists service is:

```
https://myteam.company.com/sites/TeamSite//_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
```

And I call getlistitems as follows:

```
appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
credentials = new NetworkCredential(appSettings["Username"], appSettings["Password"]);
var doclist = new Lists() { Credentials = credentials, CookieContainer = new CookieContainer() };
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
queryOptions.InnerXml = "<ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive'/>";
XmlNode doc = doclist.GetListItems("Lists", string.Empty, query, viewFields, "0", queryOptions, null);
```

I always get an error when calling the getlistitems method. Is there anything wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: yup from my point of view as well it seems like the code looks ok. would the url for my list service be incorrect if the calendar I'm querying is in a sub folder?

My url for my list service is:
    https://myteam.company.com/sites/TeamSite//_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

While my url for the calendar I'm trying to query is:
    https://myteam.company.com/sites/TeamSite/Lists/Calendar

I'll have to get back to you on the exact error message but would you think if what I said above is valid? Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you mean with sub folder? both the service and the calendar need to be in the same subsite (SPWeb to be precise) so that the service can find the list.. which seems to be the case. found out whats wrong -- see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah now i know what's wrong ;-) you aren't targeting the calendar! since the calendar exists under

```
https://myteam.company.com/sites/TeamSite/Lists/Calendar
```

you need to call the GetListItems method as followed:

```
XmlNode doc = doclist.GetListItems("Calendar", string.Empty, query, viewFields, "0", queryOptions, null);
```