# Download files from sharepoint with Java

Tags: java, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am new to Sharepoint and I am trying to write a java program to process csv files which are stored in sharepoint document library. I learned that there is a new REST API for sharepoint but it seems that it needs an authentication with app registration, but I don't have admin permission on that sharepoint site so I cannot use the REST API (?). Therefore I choose to use soap.

The url for that document library page is like:

```
http://sharepoint/sites/pitpublishing/sales/Management_Distribution/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2Fpitpublishing%2Fsales%2FManagement_Distribution%2FClar_Data&FolderCTID=0x012000C12183D9A264144BBD3D315xxxxxxx&View={F7D1xxx-62FD-428B-80EE-C44xxxxxx}
```

I am so confused about sharepoint consuming with soap. I have downloaded the wsdl files from

```
http://sharepoint/sites/pitpublishing/sales/_vti_bin/copy.asmx?WSDL
```

and created the stubs for them. I think there should be a method like getDocumentLibrary(), which directory manipulates the document library, but I only find something relates to List, Copy and View, and many relates to List. I don't know what parameters I should provide them, I have tried

```
http://sharepoint/sites/pitpublishing/sales/Management_Distribution
```

but always get error at getListItems():

```
SEVERE: Exception. See stacktrace.javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
```

If I set the List name with a list under the same site, getListItems() will return null.

Is there anyone who can help me out? Thank you very much!

EDIT:

The code that I was using is actually a tutorial code from [this blog](https://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-java-tutorial/) .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//      if(args.length != 3) {
//          logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "This must be called with parameters: <userId> <password> <config file path>");
//          return;
//      }

    try {
        String userId = args[0];
        String password = args[1];
        WatcherConfig config = WatcherConfig.loadConfig("C:\\Desktop\\sharepoint\\watcherConfig.xml");//; //args[2];args[2]);
        Authenticator.setDefault(new FnmAuthenticator(userId, password));

        Lists stub1 = new Lists(config.getListsWsdlUrl());
        ListsSoap listService = stub1.getListsSoap();
        List<SPDocument> docs = getDocuments(listService, config.getListName(), null, "100");

        Copy stub2 = new Copy(config.getCopyWsdlUrl());
        CopySoap copyService = stub2.getCopySoap();     

        //process document
        for(SPDocument doc: docs) {
            //make sure we download all attachments first
            if(!doc.isEmail())
                processDocument(listService, copyService, config, doc);
        }

        for(SPDocument doc: docs) {
            //after we download all attachments, we process the emails.
            if(doc.isEmail())
                processDocument(listService, copyService, config, doc);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

and a part of getDocuments() is here:

```
public static List<SPDocument> getDocuments(ListsSoap port, String listName,
        ArrayList<String> listColumnNames, String rowLimit) {

    List<SPDocument> docs = new ArrayList<SPDocument>();

    if (port != null && listName != null 
            && rowLimit != null) {

        try {
            // Here are additional parameters that may be set
            String viewName = "{534xxxx-4D8B-4B1D-91E3-D2ECB6xxxxx}";
            GetListItems.ViewFields viewFields = null;
            GetListItems.Query query = null;
            GetListItems.QueryOptions queryOptions = null;
            String webID = "";

            // Calling the List Web Service
            GetListItemsResponse.GetListItemsResult result = port
                    .getListItems(listName, viewName, query, viewFields,
                            rowLimit, queryOptions, webID);

            Object listResult = result.getContent().get(0);
            ......
```

Watcherconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:watcherConfig xmlns:ns2="com.fanniemae.integration.sharepoint.clients">
<dispatcherList>
    <dispatcherConfig matchingPattern="*" invokingCommand="D:\java\jdk15\bin\java.exe"/>
</dispatcherList>
<spDocumentArchiveUrl>http://sharepoint/sites/pitpublishing/sales/Management_Distribution/Clari_Data</spDocumentArchiveUrl>
<spDocumentInUrl>http://sharepoint/sites/pitpublishing/sales/Management_Distribution/Clari_Data</spDocumentInUrl>
<documentWorkingDir>C:\Desktop\sharepoint</documentWorkingDir>

<listsWsdlPath>C:\Desktop\sharepoint\Lists.wsdl</listsWsdlPath>
<copyWsdlPath>C:\Desktop\sharepoint\Copy.wsdl</copyWsdlPath>
<viewsWsdlPath>C:\Desktop\sharepoint\Views.wsdl</viewsWsdlPath>

<rowLimit>100000</rowLimit>
```

Comment: Does this [Stack article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852907/soapserverexception-when-calling-getlistitems) help? If not, can you include the code that you're using that relates to the calling of the data?

Comment: You mentioned REST but you are using web services which are different things

Comment: @Graham No... the files are under a folder called Clar_Data, which is in a document library called Management_Distribution. They are not in List, so I don't think I can use getListItems().

Comment: @Luis I meant I was trying to use REST, but when I read the document I found that it needs app registration, which I am not able to do

Comment: From the standpoint of code, document libraries are just a type of list that contain an object type of document which has some additional properties vs list items. getListItems() should work.

Comment: It is easy using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299629/sharepoint-api-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to access those files with Python, please check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141188/400-error-when-downloading-file-from-sharepoint-rest-api)

Comment: any Luck for how to do it in Java

Comment: Same here, what's the steps for java.