# Sharepoint API for Java

Tags: java, sharepoint

Steps that I am trying to perform the following steps through Java:

1) Connect to a sharepoint site with a given URL.

2) Get the list of files listed on that page

3) Filter the files using Modified date

4) Perform some more checks using Create Date and Modified Date

5) And finally save that file(s) into the Unix box.

As of now, I am able to access a particular file and read through it.
However I need to get hold of file's metadata before reading it.
Is there an API or a way to do all these in Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

With SharePoint 2013, the [REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx) services will make your life easier. In previous versions, you could use the good old [SOAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms494732.aspx) web services.

For instance, you could connect to a list with this query on the REST API:

```
http://server/site/_api/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
```

This will give you all items from that list. With OData you can do additional stuff like filtering:

```
$filter=StartDate ge datetime'2015-05-21T00%3a00%3a00'
```

Additionally, you can provide CAML queries to these services, allowing you to define detailed queries. Here's an example in Javascript:

```
var re = new SP.RequestExecutor(webUrl);
re.executeAsync({
url: "http://server/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/GetItems",
method: 'POST',
headers: { 
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  },
body: { 
    "query" : {
      "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.CamlQuery" 
      },
      "ViewXml": "<View>" +
        "<Query>" + query + "</Query>" +                       
      "</View>"
    }
  },
success: successHandler,
error: errorHandler
});
```

If all of this doesn't provide enough flexibility, you might as well take these list items in memory and do additional work in your (server side) code.

Comment: totally still has the soap web services on 2013 and 2016 even.

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza Of course but why would you want to do that if you can use modern technologies/standards like REST?

Comment: someone said "previous versions" but the current versions still support it.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a Sharepoint Rest API java wrapper that allows you to use most common operations of the rest API.

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java