# sharepoint API using Golang?

Tags: api, go, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i want to know is there any example or package of golang developed for SHAREPOINT,
Please suggest,
authenticate sharepoint using golang api,
listing all the documents in sharepoint,
getting document from sharepoint to local using api.
above are some of the basic operations that an be done.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there aren't any libraries yet, but SharePoint 2013 and later version(s) have powerful [REST APIs](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service) you can use to interact with SharePoint objects. If there were libraries for Golang, I'd assume they were nothing more than a wrapper around the REST apis.

There's plenty of [documentation](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints) and [examples](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints) that will help you with that. I answered a similar question here for [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299629/sharepoint-api-for-java/30365510#30365510) a while ago.